# blank page not created

Tags: blank-page

I create a blank page using

```
\newcommand\blankpage{ %comando pagina vuota
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \newpage}
```

Here it is one my page:

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
\addtocounter{page}{-1}

\null\vspace{\stretch{1}}
    \begin{flushright}
        \emph{Stay hungry, \\
        stay foolish. \\}
        \smallskip
        Steve Jobs, Stanford University, 2005
    \end{flushright}
\vspace{\stretch{5}}\null
```

Unfortunately adding \blankpage after that page, it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `\blankpage` only contains one `\newpage`, i.e. the leading `\null` is put on the current page. It only works as expected if a page break occurred already direct beforehand. To make it always work you need to add a `\newpage` at the beginning. Should there be already be a page break, this `\newpage` will be ignored, so you don't get two extra pages.

```
\newcommand\blankpage{% comando pagina vuota
    \newpage
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \newpage
}
```